# How to Set .env with JS

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, calendly

I have this, from https://npm.io/package/node-calendly-sdk.

```
calendly_client = new Calendly("YOUR-API-TOKEN")
```

I'm confused on how to set .env varibles in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Env variables are a set of values, generally to store sensitive data that shouldn't be in the code.

In nodejs, you can add the npm package **dotenv** with: `npm i dotenv`, then, you have to create a file named .env in the root directory of your project and define your variable like:

**.env file:**

```
API_KEY_TOKEN = "some value"
```

Then, at the very beginning of your nodejs file, write: `require("dotenv").config();` and that's it, you can access your .env variables with process.env

Full example:

```
require("dotenv").config();
calendly_client = new Calendly(process.env.API_KEY_TOKEN );
```

For a complete documentation visit [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)